# Chrome headless with Puppeteer, how to catch js crash?

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I'm running Chrome in headless mode with Puppeteer, and I discovered that if an URL I load contain a javascript code like:

```
while (true) {console.log('crash')}
```

The page will load forever even though I have timeout set in place and waitUntil defined:

```
await page.goto('http://...', {waitUntil: ['load', 'documentloaded', 'networkidle0'], 'timeout': timeout})
```

How can I ensure that no JS (or any other kind of) abuse don't stuck my code?

Comment: Need to take a deeper look, but I think it is related to https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2395

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: => https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/. You are on a path to a neverending work...

Comment: How'd you do that cool effect on your pic is that a photoshop filter?  @CyrilN.

Comment: @FabricioG Ah thanks :) No, I paid someone on Fiverr to do that from one of my photo (https://www.fiverr.com/fajarajaf/make-a-unique-popart-portrait-wpap-of-your-photo)